# Spot start and end index of values outside specified bounds?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays of size n :

```
let values = [5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];
let min_arr = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3];
let max_arr = [7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7];
let n = values.length;
```

I am trying to spot the indexes of the start and end of the "zones" where `min_arr[i] > values[i]` or `max_arr[i] < values[i]`.
In the previous arrays the first zone : `values[4] = 7 > 6 = max_arr[4]` and `!(values[5] = 6 > 6 = max_arr[5])` thus `start = 4` and `end = 5`.
In the previous arrays the second zone : `values[8] = 3 < 4 = min_arr[8]` and `values[9] = 3 < 4 = min_arr[9]` but `!(values[10] = 4 < 3 = min_arr[10])` thus `start = 8` and `end = 10`.
In the previous arrays the expected output would be : `[[4, 5], [8, 10]]`.
Nb: It does not matter if the last end index is greater than n.
Here is my code so far :

```
let temp = values
  .map((e, i) => min_arr[i] > e || max_arr[i] < e ? i : undefined)
  .filter((e) => e);
console.log(temp);
```

**Output**

```
[4, 8, 9]
```

My logic here is to first get all the indexes where the value is not in the bounds before removing consecutive values and adding the `end` value.

```
let res = [];
let start = temp[0];
for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
  if (i + 1 == temp.length) {
    res.push([start, temp[i] + 1]);
    break;
  }
  if (temp[i] + 1 != temp[i + 1]) {
    res.push([start, temp[i] + 1]);
    start = temp[i + 1];
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

**Output**

```
[[4, 5], [8, 10]]
```

As a beginner in JavaScript, I find this method **crude** and I believe that the whole process can be done in a **declarative way**. How should I proceed ?

Please don't hesitate to edit this question if it lacks clarity.

Comment: What would be the expected result if min_arr or max_arr had multiple zones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are not so crude methods, probably they are in declarative way, also with handling some corner-cases. Corner cases i mean in result you are expencting arrays with 2 elements, open index and close index. So if the last element in array is out of bound - still an array with 2 elements will be returned. And at this point im curious about the correct output, probably you have to clarify it a bit. I assumed that indexes shoult be "first index of item that is out of bounds" and "last index of item that is out of bounds", not the "last index + 1"

```js
let values = [5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];
let min_arr = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3];
let max_arr = [7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7];

function getZones(values, predicateFn) {
  const reduced = values.reduce(
    (acc, curr, i) => {
      const isMet = predicateFn(curr, i);

      if (isMet) {
        if (acc._zone) acc._zone[1] = i;
        else acc._zone = [i];
      } else if (acc._zone) {
        // -1 due to current index is ok, previous was not.
        acc._zone[1] = i - 1;
        acc.result.push(acc._zone);
        acc._zone = undefined;
      }
      return acc;
    },
    {
      _zone: undefined,
      result: []
    }
  );

  // Case when zone was opened and not closed.
  // Happens for last item only.
  const { _zone, result } = reduced;
  if (_zone) {
    if (_zone.length === 1) {
      _zone[1] = _zone[0];
    }
    result.push(_zone);
  }

  return result;
}

const res = getZones(values, (curr, i) => curr < min_arr[i] || curr > max_arr[i]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Test set i checked with:

```
const testSets = [
  {
    // Original set
    values: [5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5],
    min_arr: [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3],
    max_arr: [7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]
    // [[4,4],[8,9]]
  },
  {
    // with starting and ending outs
    values: [2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 10],
    min_arr: [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3],
    max_arr: [7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]
    // [[0,0],[4,4],[8,9],[12,12]]
  },
  {
    // with starting and ending "wave"
    values: [2, 8, 2, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 10],
    min_arr: [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    max_arr: [7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7]
    // [[0,2],[4,4],[8,9],[11,13]]
  },
  {
    // Completely out of bounds
    values: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
    min_arr: [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    max_arr: [7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7]
    // [[0,13]]
  }
];
```

Also, here is a codesandbox so you can check the correct output and behavior.

[image: Edit modern-architecture-y5786x]

Answer (score 0):

Your method will work only for 2 consecutive values , try an example with more  consecutive values like `[[2, 7], [8, 11]]` and check your method .

The solution can be the next:

```
let values = [5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5];
let min_arr = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3];
let max_arr = [7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7];

const result = values
  .map((num, i) => (min_arr[i] > num || max_arr[i] < num ? i : undefined))
  .reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    if ((currentValue || currentValue === 0) && !array[currentIndex - 1]) {
      const findNextSibling = array.slice(currentIndex).findIndex(i => !i);
      const finalConsecutiveValue =
        findNextSibling === -1 || findNextSibling === 0
          ? 1
          : findNextSibling + currentIndex;

      previousValue.push([currentValue, finalConsecutiveValue]);
    }

    return previousValue;
  }, []);
    
    console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: Thanks @SergeySosunov , I changed the code to solve the given problems .

Can you check now ?